# How to add maxdate and mindate to mat-calendar in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

I am using Angular 6 material design mat-calendar.
I am referring the below example.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-calendar?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

But in mat-calendar how to set min and max proporty.

```
 <mat-calendar [selected]="selectedDate" (selectedChange)="onSelect($event)"></mat-calendar>
```

I am trying to add like this, but it is not working.

```
<mat-calendar [selected]="selectedDate" (selectedChange)="onSelect($event)" [min]="mindate" [max]="maxdate"></mat-calendar>
```

But this is throwing error "**Can't bind to 'min' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-calendar'**."

Anyone can help me in this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use `[minDate]` not `[min]` similarly `[maxDate]`

In Html:

```
  <mat-calendar [selected]="selectedDate" 
       (selectedChange)="onSelect($event)" 
       [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate"></mat-calendar>
```

In component:

```
  minDate = new Date(2018, 0, 1);
  maxDate = new Date(2020, 2, 1);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-calendar-pauykr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thank you for that... much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
**TS**

minDate = new Date(2017, 0, 1);

**HTML**

<mat-calendar [selected]="selectedDate" (selectedChange)="onSelect($event)" [minDate] = "minDate"></mat-calendar>
```

I hope it helps you out

Comment: This is not working. Throwing error in console.
"Can't bind to 'min' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-calendar'."  @yash Rami